# how to compare character against set of given characters in C?

Tags: c, string, compare, string.h, strncmp

I'd like to be able to compare a character on `stdin` with a characters of my specification. The purpose of this is to filter out every other input as wrong, while maintaining only the specified single chars as commands. **Like on `stdin` "nn" or "qddaw" -> wrong go again but "n" make something useful.**

Here is what I have in mind "code-wise":

```
if (input does not contain 'c' or 's' or 'q' or 'n') { 
    printf("some kind of error");
}
```

Well I tried to create an array with specified characters like `array[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'}` so I could be able to compare it with a string on the stdin with function strncmp.. like

```
char c[256];
scanf("%s", c)
if (strncmp(array, c, 1) != 0) printf("error");
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

**Edit1:** Here is actual piece of code:

```
char c[256];
char* s = "nsrld";
char* quiter = "q";

do 
    {
        printf(">");
        scanf("%s", c);
        if (only when there is no 'n' or 's' or other char from char* s on input)
        {
            errorHandle(ERROR_WRONG_CMD);
        }
        scanf("%*[^\n]"); scanf("%*c");
    } while (strcmp(c,quiter) != 0);
```

as you can see I handled the 'q' thing quite well, but multiple chars are pain in the ass. Thanks for any advice.

**Edit 2:** or in other words I need a function which will compare input with a set of given characters and only if there is one **OR** another (like 'q' or 's' the function will pass (but not if there are characters together like 'qs')

Comment: With getchar(), did you try printing out `c`? Print it out like this: printf("c = %c / %d\n", c, c); Also, what is the type of `c`, `char` or `int`?

Comment: @GeorgeSkoptsov I edited the post because I actually need to distinguish input "qdqqdq" from "q" in which case only standalone "q" will do the work and any other input will report an error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I didn't make myself clear enough. What I need is input "type what ever you want" like "wwqwqe" and do the error unless the input is just 'c' or just 's' (and a few more).*

```
char usersInput[200] = "";            /* A buffer to hold the input values */
char *result = gets(usersInput);      /* Fill the buffer from stdin */
if (result != NULL)                   /* If we got something */
{
    if (strlen(usersInput) == 1)      /* the input must be exactly 1 character */
    {
        char ch = usersInput[0];
        if (strchr(ch, "csqn") == NULL)    /* It must be a valid values */
        {
            printf("Evil Bad Character <%c>\n", ch);
        }
        else
        {
            /* Do stuff with the known valid input value ch */
        }
    }
    else
    {
        puts("The input value must be exactly 1 character\n");
        puts("and must be 'c', 's', 'q' or 'n'");
    }
}
else
{
    puts("EOF or ERROR while reading stdin\n");
}
```

This should do the job.

One warning.   **gets** is not smart enough to know that **usersInput** is 200 characters long.

It will gleefully let you type in 201 characters or more, which overwrites other characters in memory. That sort of thing can lead to hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: hmm and if I want to have the infinite loop as on my example [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10162127/1333847) and I want to return error after hitting "enter" twice ..  what do I do? in my version I can hit enter as many times as I want and nothing happens, it's still waiting for another input..

Answer (score 1):

```
char c = getchar();
switch (c) {
case 'c':
case 's':
case 'q':
case 'n':
  do_something();
  break;
default:
  print_error();
};
```

The above code should work.  I don't know why your if statement wasn't working.  Generally a switch works well in this type of scenario too.

Comment: the problem here is with getchar as it takes only one char so input like "cawwffawf" will pass this test. What I need is when input is like "caawfaw" printf error but when input is exactly one character "c" do something useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
int ch = getchar();
if (ch != EOF)
{
    if (strchr("csqn", ch) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Evil Bad Character <%c> in Hex %02X\n", ch, ch);
    }
    else
    {
        /* Do stuff with ch */
    }
}
else
{
    printf("EOF on input\n");
}
```

Comment: I have edited the first post to reflect my needs. I need to be able to distinguish input "cwdwdaf" from 'c' in which case only 'c' will make something useful any other input will parse an error.

Comment: Your question and examples are misleading.  getchar gets one character at a time.  If you want to deal with checking all of the input, then performing some action, you need to rework your question.

Comment: yeah sorry for the confusion, I have already figured it out, thank you for your time and effort, I really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Write a function

```
int IsGood(int c)
{
    if(c=='a'||c=='b'||c=='c')
    return 1;
    else
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have edited the first post to reflect my needs. I need to be able to distinguish input "cwdwdaf" from 'c' in which case only 'c' will make something useful any other input will parse an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution should work. If that's the exact same code you posted - then your problem *might* because the printf needs a newline at the end to flush to console.

Answer (score 0):

I have thought the string as sets... So if the intersection of them is the void set then we will fail -> printf("Error")... otherwise the output is none...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int intersection(char* source, char* search)
{
  int i,j;
  for(i = 0; i < strlen(search); i++)
    if(strchr(source,search[i]))j++;
  if(j != strlen(search))return 0;
  else return 1;
}

int main()
{
  char *letters = "eo";
  char *p = "hello";
  int e = intersection(p,letters);
  if(e==1)puts("Non Void");  
  else puts("Void");
}
```

Comment: thank you for this code, but maybe I didn't make myself clear enough. What I need is input "type what ever you want" like "wwqwqe" and do the error unless the input is just 'c' or just 's' (and a few more). With your code, if I will specify p as set of "cs" even input like "cs" will pass. The code 'q' ends the prog.
   `char c[256];
    char* s = "nsrld";
    char* quiter = "q";
    do 
    {
        printf(">");
        scanf("%s", c);
        if (dunno)
        {
            errorHandle(ERROR_WRONG_CMD);
        }
        scanf("%*[^\n]"); scanf("%*c");
    } while (strcmp(c,quiter) != 0);`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    char c[256];
    char* s = "nqsrld";
    char* quiter = "q";

    do 
    {
        printf(">");
        scanf("%s", c);
        if ((strpbrk(s, c) == 0) || (strlen(c) >= 2))
        {
            errorHandle(ERROR_WRONG_CMD);
        }
        scanf("%*[^\n]"); scanf("%*c");
    } while (strcmp(c,quiter) != 0);
```

Thanks to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 0):

While it looks as if you've got a solution, it might be worth mentioning that what you're asking for doesn't sound as if it's all that far away from the standard 'getopt' functionality...  See http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html for example.